# What is a good source that will help me classify protists?

Tags: microbiology, database, microscopy, classification

I am a 15 year old that enjoys looking at the micro world. The only issue that I have is that I can't find a good online source that will help me classify the name of the micro organism that I'm looking at. Does anyone know a place that will help me do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look at [Cavalier-Smith's](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S093247390470108X) classification of protists.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: it's pretty old

Comment: @har-wradim Any free sources?

Comment: If you need an overview of higher taxa than [this scheme from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Eukaryota) seems be a good starting point (see also the papers they cite).

Comment: @har-wradim: could you turn your comment into an answer? It seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While not comprehensive, the [Portal to Protistology](http://protozoa.uga.edu/portal/reference.html) has many resources for exploring the diversity of protozoa. I especially recommend their [videos](http://protozoa.uga.edu/portal/images_sartiano.html) that are really fascinating, focus on distinguishing features of different protists, and may be helpful for identification to some degree. But given your interest you should just explore all the pages on the site, check out the books they recommend (e.g. the Illustrated Guide to Protozoa), and see what is useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else decide to post anything that was put in the comments as an answer I decided to.

There is an excellent article from Wikipedia on the subject, found [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Eukaryota). It was also recommended in the comments that you should read the sources provided.

I also found this PDF to be quite helpful, [Nebraska Med](http://www.nebraskamed.com/app_files/pdf/careers/education-programs/asp/guidebook.pdf).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a CBOL working group that categorizes protists based on genomic sequencing and barcoding. Here is a link to their publication: [CBOL Protist Working Group: Barcoding Eukaryotic Richness beyond the Animal, Plant, and Fungal Kingdoms](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1001419)

Comment: No offense, but I don't think a casual teenage biologist has access to high-throughout sequencing technology